# Access LAN with Nordvpn tunel

Tags: openvpn

Hello I have an NordVPN access. I have an IP Camera with WebUI.I have an Synology MR2200ac . I have an Android 14 Phone. I would like to access My Camera from phone if i connect to NordVPN with OpenVPN App with my Android and if i connect my Synology router to the same nodvpn server or User account.